# how to find words before a character in a string

Tags: string, python-3.x

I am writing an E-mail authentication checker in python and I'm stuck on how to check for a name/company name before the @ symbol. I have no clue on how to get round this problem. I have made the check for the @ symbol and the . before the domain, but I cant check to see if this is a valid email because it wont check for the name/company name before the @ symbol.

Help would be greatly appreciated. I am also new here to this website so this might be a very simple solution.

```
    def search():
        email = input("Please enter your email adress \n")

    #This checks for the @ symbol in the e-mail adress
        if "@"  in str(email):
            print ("The @ symbol is correct")

        else:
            print("The email adress provided is not vaild because there was no @ symbol")


    #This checks for the . to be present in the email
        if "." in str(email):
            print ("The . is correct")

        else:
            print("The email adress provided is not valid because there was no .")



    #Checks to see if the string only contains letters

        if email.isalpha():
            print('Your email only contains letters')


    #Checks for a symbol clash
        if "@." or ".@" in str(email):
            print("You cannot have two symbols together")





        #This completes the email checking
        if "." in str(email): 
            if "@" in str(email) :
                if ".@" or "@." in str(email)== false:
                    print ("Your email has been registered")

    search()








    #Repeats the process of email checking so that the user can try again
    def main():
        carry_on='y'
        while carry_on=='y':
            search()
            carry_on=input("Try again? (y/n)")

    main()
```

Comment: You can have ".@" and "@." in an email. For instance, `"very.unusual.@.unusual.com"@example.com` is a valid email address. The easiest way to determine if an email address is valid is, send an email to the address and wait for a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is to use `str.index` and slicing:

```
>>> email = "fakeemail@server.com"
>>> email[:email.index('@')]
'fakeemail'
```

However, as Kevin notes in the comments, it is not as easy as you think to validate an email address.